# Pass value to parent in class declaration in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I was watching a screencast with Jim Weirich where he started to do something like this:

```
class Subuser < User("Type")
end
```

Does Ruby let you pass arguments when defining a parent class? I can't come up with an example where that would actually work.

Comment: [Peepcode](https://peepcode.com/products/play-by-play-jimweirich-ruby) play by play with Jim Weirich

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that by declaring a method `User` which takes an argument and returns a class:

```
class Admin
end

class Client
end

def User(arg)
  case arg
    when :admin
      Admin
    when :client
      Client
  end
end

class Subuser < User(:admin)
end

Subuser.superclass
# => Admin
```

Comment: Wizardry like this, while cool in a screencast, is not very fun for other people to maintain. Remember "other people" often includes your future self that forgot what this sort of thing means. With any luck you'll be able to find this answer and refresh your memory when that happens, but it's best avoided in the first place.

Comment: How is this "wizardry"? Capitalized methods are common (e.g. `Integer("1")`) and inheriting from expressions are common (e.g. `class whatever < Struct.new(:a,:b,:c)`). There's nothing wrong with this, other than it's unexpected that `User(:admin)` doesn't return a subclass of `User`, but even that is forgivable if they both quack like ducks.

Comment: The Struct example is different as it is the new method on Struct, i.e. it looks like a method. The only other example I encountered in the stdlib is one of the delegation class (don't remember which one).

Comment: @Joshua Creek - the only capitalized methods I see are the conversion methods that are def'd in Kernel (Integer, Float, Array) but these return an object of their type not a class. So yes I agree with tadman, this code stinks.

Comment: I don't see how it matters where they're defined. It is a language feature, regardless of whether you like it or not. It is used in common and popular libraries (e.g. nokogiri's `Nokogiri::HTML(the_html)`, camping's `class Digits < R '/nuts/(\d+)'`, FactoryGirl's `Factory(:user, :name => 'Joe')`, the stdlib's `Pathname "/some/path"` and `URI "http://www.legit-quotes.com"` and `BigMath::PI(precision)`). On one of my larger client projects, there are 67 capitalized methods, none of which we defined ourselves.

Comment: stdlib's [`DelegateClass`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Object.html#method-i-DelegateClass) is called this way, too: `class MyClass < DelegateClass(ClassToDelegateTo)`